# Is an algebraic space having a monomorphism to an affine scheme a scheme?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, schemes, algebraic-spaces

### Definition

An **algebraic space** is a functor $X$ from the opposite of the category of commutative rings to the category of sets satisfying the following conditions:

1. The functor $X$ is a (large) etale sheaf.
2. For any morphisms $\operatorname{Spec}A\to X\gets\operatorname{Spec}B$, the pullback is a scheme.
3. There is a scheme $Y$ and a surjection $Y\to X$ that is etale (this makes sense when Condition 2 is satisfied).

Contrary to Knutson's convention, we do not require algebraic spaces to be quasi-separated.

### Question

If $X$ is an algebraic space and $i\colon X\hookrightarrow\operatorname{Spec}A$ is an injection to an affine scheme, can we conclude that $X$ is a scheme?

Note that no finiteness condition is imposed on $i$.

Comment: I don't think this is known.